# error: expression ""00000000000000000000000000000000"" has 32 elements ; expected 33 elements

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

This is the code segment that generates the stated error:

```
architecture sm1 of SM is

...
signal sum_1 : float (5 downto -27);
...

begin   

N_PROCESS: process (N, j, CLK)

    ...

begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        ...

        sum_1 <= to_float(0);

        ...
    end if;
end process;

end sm1;
```

The error is related to the sum_1 signal. Can someone shed some light on why it happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Without any declarations? Not a chance. Beyond pointing out the obvious : the error message tells you exactly what's wrong; `sum_1` is 33 bits long and the declaration of `to_float` must be written to give a 32-bit return value. Change either of these appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`3 downto 0` has 4 elements: 3,2,1,0.

`5 downto -27` has 33 elements

You are making a classic [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).